# Cron job for 7 days alone not followed by multiple weeks

Tags: linux, cron, job-scheduling, cron-task

I need to execute a cronjob to run once for 7 days alone.I have tried like this:

```
 0 0 * * 0-6  myscript.sh
```

It gets run for once a day and running every day of the week since i gave as 0-6.

But i need to run a job for one week alone not followed by multiple days.I donot want to mention the date of the month,since i need randomly.

(or)

Is it possible through "at" command if it is not through "cron"???

How can i set job to run for 7 days alone guys????

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "for one week alone"? `cron` is for running things repeatedly forever

Comment: Anyway, this is off-topic for SO. SO is for programming questions, not questions about using Unix subsystems like `cron`. superuser.com or unix.stackexchange.com are the place for those questions.